# Inline style interpolation not working angular9

Tags: css, interpolation, angular9, inline-styles

I would like to pass my component property values to inline css.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'width': '{{ object.value }}%' }">
```

The method is not working and getting error:-

```
 Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
```

Comment: Without {{ and }} just `[ngStyle]="{ 'width': object.value + '%' }"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Use one of below syntax

```
[style.width.%]="object.value"
```

Or

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'width.%': object.value }"
```